# Reference compound primary key

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I'm new to Slick and this is my first attempt of creating an application with it.

I have a `case class User(userID: UUID, firstName: String, lastName: String)`.

Users can log in.
This is where `case class LoginInfo(providerID: String, providerKey: String)` comes in (I'm using [Silhouette](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette) for authentication).

I'd like to associate every `User` with a `LoginInfo` using a Slick `Table`:

```
class UsersWithLoginInfos(tag:Tag) extends Table[(PrimaryKey, UUID)](tag, "USERS_WITH_LOGIN_INFOS"){
  def loginInfoID = TableQuery[LoginInfos].shaped.value.loginInfoID
  def userID = column[UUID]("USER_ID")
  def * = (loginInfoID, userID) <>(UserWithLoginInfo.tupled, UserWithLoginInfo.unapply)
}
```

This is the corresponding `case class UserWithLoginInfo(loginInfoID: PrimaryKey, userID: UUID)`.

My tables for `User`s and `LoginInfo`s are straightforward:

```
class LoginInfos(tag: Tag) extends Table[LoginInfo](tag, "LOGIN_INFOS") {

  // The primary key of this table is compound: it consists of the provider's ID and its key
  def loginInfoID = primaryKey("LOGIN_INFO_ID", (providerID, providerKey))

  // "credentials" for example
  def providerID = column[String]("PROVIDER_ID")

  // "admin@nowhere.com" for example
  def providerKey = column[String]("PROVIDER_KEY")

  def * = (providerID, providerKey) <>(LoginInfo.tupled, LoginInfo.unapply)
}
class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "USERS") {

  def id = column[UUID]("ID", O.PrimaryKey)

  def firstName = column[String]("FIRST_NAME")

  def lastName = column[String]("LAST_NAME")

  def * = (id, firstName, lastName) <>(User.tupled, User.unapply)
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't typecheck:

```
def * = (loginInfoID, userID) <>(UserWithLoginInfo.tupled, UserWithLoginInfo.unapply)
```

> Expression of type MappedProjection[UserWithLoginInfo, (PrimaryKey,
>   UUID)] doesn't conform to expected type ProvenShape[(PrimaryKey,
>   UUID)]

I could work around this by introducing a `case class LoginInfoWithID(info: LoginInfo, id: UUID)` but I hope to get away with referencing `LoginInfo`'s compound primary key directly.

Is there a way to do this? Or am I on the wrong track entirely?

I'm using Slick 3.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve here, but if it is just to get an `User` with its associated `LoginfInfo` (untested code ahead):

```
class LoginInfos(tag: Tag) extends Table[LoginInfo](tag, "LOGIN_INFOS") {
  def providerID = column[String]("PROVIDER_ID")
  def providerKey = column[String]("PROVIDER_KEY")

  def * = (providerID, providerKey) <>(LoginInfo.tupled, LoginInfo.unapply)
  def pk = primaryKey("PK_LOGIN_INFO_ID", (providerID, providerKey))
}

class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "USERS") {
  def id = column[UUID]("ID", O.PrimaryKey)
  def firstName = column[String]("FIRST_NAME")
  def lastName = column[String]("LAST_NAME")

  def * = (id, firstName, lastName) <>(User.tupled, User.unapply)
}

class UsersWithLoginInfos(tag:Tag) extends Table[(providerID: String, providerKey: String, UUID: String)](tag, "USERS_WITH_LOGIN_INFOS"){
  def providerID = column[String]("USER_PROVIDER_ID")   //  column name assumption
  def providerKey = column[String]("USER_PROVIDER_KEY") //  column name assumption
  def userID = column[UUID]("USER_ID")

  def pk = primaryKey("PK_USER_WITH_LOGIN_INFO_ID", (providerID, providerKey))
}


case class UserWithLoginInfo(user: User, loginInfo: LoginInfo)
```

You can optionally wrap the `Tuple3` in `UsersWithLoginInfos`in a case class if you like to. However, this is an example query to get an `User` joined with its `LoginInfo`:

```
def findUserWithLoginInfo(providerID: String, providerKey: String): Future[Option[UserWithLoginInfo]] = {
  val query = (for {
    user <- TableQuery[Users] if user.providerID === providerID && user.providerKey === providerKey
    userToLoginInfo <- TableQuery[UsersWithLoginInfos] if userToLoginInfo.userID === user.id
    loginInfo <- TableQuery[LoginInfos] if userToLoginInfo.providerID === loginInfo.providerID && userToLoginInfo.providerID === loginInfo.providerKey
  } yield UserWithLoginInfo(user, loginInfo))

  db.run(query.result.headOption)
}
```

Instead of writing a rather verbose query like above, you can also define a foreign key constraint as it is described here [Slick documentation, Constraints](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/schemas.html#constraints).

Also I found [Coming from ORM to Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/orm-to-slick.html) very useful when I started using slick. Remember, slick is NOT an ORM and thus it does things quite different :)